# problem with xampp Localhost showing "Index of" page

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I have this problem with xampp localhost:

Whenever i change my **index.php** to something else it shows "Index of"! Normally if I leave **index.php** the website will load up. ut I want the **challenge.php** page to appear.

Here are some images to help.

The vs code with index.php:
[image]

The localhost. the website loads perfectly because its in index.php
[image]

The vs code when I change it to challenge.php
[image]

The localhost - Now when I change it to challenge.php i see the Index of
[image]

When the users visits my website they need to first complete the captcha challenge and afterwards they can gain access to the website.

Comment: You don't need to rename the file, just leave it as index.php. Or, you can write code in index.php so it redirects the user to challenge.php automatically if they have not yet completed the capture (I assume you store the result of this in the Session??). Or, you can reconfigure Apache (maybe using  a .htaccess setting) so that "challenge.php" is the default file for that folder.